# java code for importing xls data into mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to import `xls` file into `mysql` but getting an error of `Nullpointer EXCEPTION` please give me the solution

```
package abhi;

public class ImportData {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test","root","abhi1402");  
        con.setAutoCommit(false);  
        PreparedStatement pstm = null ;  
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("D:/New Folder/apnakhata1.xls");  
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input );  
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);  
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);  
        Row row;
        for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
            row = sheet.getRow(i);
            String CountryName = row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
            String CountryCode = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
            String BankName = row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
            String Website = row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue();
            String Name = row.getCell(5).getStringCellValue();
            String SMS = row.getCell(6).getStringCellValue();
            int SMSNumber = (int) row.getCell(7).getNumericCellValue();
            int CustomerCare = (int) row.getCell(8).getNumericCellValue();

String sql = "INSERT INTO Bank VALUES('"+CountryName+"','"+CountryCode

+"','"+BankName+"','"+Website+"','"+Name+"','"+SMS+"','"+SMSNumber

+"','"+CustomerCare+"')";

            pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstm.execute();
            System.out.println("Import rows "+i);
        }
        con.commit();
        pstm.close();
        con.close();
        input.close();
        System.out.println("Success import excel to mysql table");
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }

}

}


}

}
```

Comment: Which line throws the NullPointerException?...

Comment: Please share exception trace.

Comment: You really should be using parameters in your PreparedStatement.  If any of your text (e.g. `BankName`) has an apostrophe in it, you'll be back with another problem...

Comment: post your stack trace and also please mention which line throws exception

Comment: NullPointerException is worse exception in Java to debug :)

Comment: @ShoaibChikate : what is this supposed to mean ??

Comment: One suggestion in ur above code if you are using PreparedStatement then why you are forming sql query by concatenation which is worse practice and again you are Downcasting PreparedStatement which is no need at all

Answer (score 0):

Reason of `NullPointerException` in your code is due to

```
for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++)
```

Check your Excel file. It may contains some blank rows or may be some blank column values and then run your code.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put

```
String CountryName = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
String CountryCode = row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
String BankName = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
String Website = row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
String Name = row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue();
```