# Excel file upload in java

Tags: java, javascript, file-upload, excel-2007

I uploaded excel file data to Mysql database using java. In my excel sheet I have 33 columns data, When I am uploading data to mysql data base, only 32 columns data is inserting in database.

I am not able to get the 33 column data into database, and I am not getting any error in my console

Comment: Is it possible to upload n no.of columns data from excel sheet to mysql database using java?

Comment: Yes, maybe this could help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812695/java-code-for-importing-xls-data-into-mysql-database